# Entity Framework not updating the foreign key

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a Web API with ASP.NET Core 2.2, I'm trying to update object with `Put` method. I created this DTO object:

```c#
    public class EditUserDTO 
    {
            [MaxLength(255)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(55)]
            public string MailAdress { get; set; }
            public Guid? ProfilId { get; set; }
    }
```

My class :

```c#
    public class User 
    {
            [MaxLength(255)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(55)]
            public string MailAdress { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("ProfilId")]
            public Guid? ProfilId { get; set; }
            public virtual Profil Profil { get; set; }
    }
```

My `PUT` method :

```c#
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(Guid id, [FromBody]EditUserDTO user)
    {
        try
        {
            var userEntity = await _repoWrapper.UserRepo.GetUserByIdAsync(id);

            if (userEntity == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"User with id: {id}, hasn't been found in db.");
                return NotFound();
            }

            _mapper.Map(user, userEntity);              
            await _repoWrapper.UserRepo.UpdateUserAsync(userEntity);
            _repoWrapper.Save();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

I created an Automapper :

```c#
     public Mappers()
     {
         CreateMap<User, EditUserDTO>().ReverseMap();
     }
```

After the execution of the mapper the foreign key `ProfilId` gets the new value from the `DTO`, but the child object `Profil` has the same old value.

When I am trying to get the object from the database after executing the `PUT`, it still has the same old value.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are updating your entity with new profile id but also you are passing back the old profile.

You should make sure if that Profile exists.

You can try something like:

```c#
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(Guid id, [FromBody]EditUserDTO user)
    {
        try
        {
            var userEntity = await _repoWrapper.UserRepo.GetUserByIdAsync(id);
            var profileEntity = await _repoWrapper.ProfileRepo.GetProfileByIdAsync(user.ProfilId);

            if (userEntity == null)
            {
               _logger.LogError($"User with id: {id}, hasn't been found in db.");
               return NotFound();
            }

            if (profileEntity == null)
            {
               _logger.LogError($"Profile with id: {id}, hasn't been found in db.");
               return BadRequest();
            }

            _mapper.Map(user, userEntity);  

            userEntity.Profile = profileEntity;

            await _repoWrapper.UserRepo.UpdateUserAsync(userEntity);
            _repoWrapper.Save();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```